# How to have distributed tensorflow experiment run evaluation on worker instead of master?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm using Google Cloud ML Engine to train a model with tensorflow.contrib.learn.Experiment. By default it seems that tensorflow has the master server run the evaluations. I only run evals after the training is complete (min_eval_frequency=0), and my master has a large number of cores and RAM but no GPU (so the eval is very slow relative to the P100 workers). Can I make the eval run on a worker?

Answer (score 1):

When using `learn_runner.run`, there is no way to run evaluation on regular workers. Here are a few alternatives:

1. Use a GPU on your master.
2. Don't use `learn_runner.run`. Instead, you'll have to reproduce that functionality. To wit:

Instantiate an instance of [`RunConfig()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/run_config.py#L211). Inspect the `task_type` and invoke `Experiment.train`, `Experiment.evaluate`, or `Experiment.continuous_eval` as necessary.

That said, since the Master is basically just another worker that also does evaluation, is there any reason not to use a GPU on the Master?